# Remove Astrid "remind me" from Gmail

Tags: gmail, astrid

How do I remove the Astrid 'Remind Me' widget from Gmail?  I use Chrome, and had no trouble removing the Chrome widget, but a thorough search of Gmail help and settings turned up zilch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to remove the Astrid Tasks "extension" from Chrome.  There should be an icon on the toolbar.  Right click and select remove.